# Iterate through array of objects and remove unwanted symbols form array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to change this array of objects so that the strings are turned into numbers and the arrays are turned into something I can interate through. Im trying to make a table out of this. Heres what I tried so far:

```
function ParseData(obj) {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        obj[keys[i]] = JSON.parse(obj[keys[i]]);
    }
}
console.log(ParseData(newData));




const newData = [
    {
        apac: "[\"CN\",\"JP\"]"
        brand: '1',
        brands: '1183',
    },
    {
    apac: "[\"CN\",\"JP\"]"
        brand: '1',
        brands: '1183',
    },
];
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. A few things already... You're missing commas after your apac line in your data items, so your code is not syntactically correct. Also your data is already an array, so not sure why you're getting its keys to iterate. And your function is not returning anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through the array, and use `ParseData` function to update keys of each object in the array.

You dont have to return a value from the function, if you are updating the paramater itself. All the changes made to the parameter will be available in the `newData` variable.

```js
const newData = [
  { apac: "[\"CN\",\"JP\"]", brand: '1', brands: '1183' },
  { apac: "[\"CN\",\"JP\"]", brand: '1', brands: '1183' },
];
function ParseData(myArray) {
  myArray.forEach((node) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(node);
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      node[keys[i]] = JSON.parse(node[keys[i]]);
    }
  })
}
ParseData(newData);
console.log(newData)
```

If you want to make your `newData` unchanged and `ParseData` function return a new variable, you could store your paramater in a variable an a shallow copy. I used `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myArray))` for that.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const newData = [
  { apac: "[\"CN\",\"JP\"]", brand: '1', brands: '1183' },
  { apac: "[\"CN\",\"JP\"]", brand: '1', brands: '1183' },
];
function ParseData(myArray) {
  const clonedata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myArray));
  clonedata.forEach((node) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(node);
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      node[keys[i]] = JSON.parse(node[keys[i]]);
    }
  })
  return clonedata;
}
const output = ParseData(newData);
console.log(newData);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

newData is not an object, it is an array of objects, so you don't need to use Object.keys(). Also your function doesn't return a value so your console log won't output anything.

Since keys within your objects are always the same you can do this:

```
const newData = [
    {
        apac: "[\"CN\",\"JP\"]",
        brand: '1',
        brands: '1183',
    },
    {
            apac: "[\"CN\",\"JP\"]",
        brand: '1',
        brands: '1183',
    },
];

function ParseData(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        obj[i]['apac'] = JSON.parse(obj[i]['apac']);
        obj[i]['brand'] = parseInt(obj[i]['brand']);
        obj[i]['brands'] = parseInt(obj[i]['brands']);
    }
    return arr
}

console.log(ParseData(newData));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t57u3hyv/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one you get your output

```html
<script>
const newData = [
    {
        apac: "[\"CN\",\"JP\"]",
        brand: '1',
        brands: '1183',
    },
    {
    apac: "[\"CN\",\"JP\"]",
        brand: '1',
        brands: '1183',
    },
];

function ParseData(obj) {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        
        var b=JSON.stringify(obj[keys[i]]);
        str = b.replace(/\\/g, '');
        obj[keys[i]] = str;
    }
    return obj;
}
console.log(ParseData(newData));

</script>
```